# Getting a String from a TextView, pass it to a variable and pass it to other activity

Tags: android, android-activity, textview

everyone,

I'm trying to set up a TextView on the MainActivity to get a query from the user and then pass the query string to a variable which should be passed to another activity, which will had the query string to a url in order to show a search on a WebView defined on the MainActivity.

This is my MainActivity, not concluded yet, since I'm having trouble going on from here.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
String query;

TextView term =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView intView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    intView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

}

public void openWikipedia(View view){

     Intent intent = new Intent(this, Wikipedia.class);
     intent.putExtra("query", query);
     startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The Wikipedia activity, should receive the query string and add it to a string to finish the url to do a search on the Wikipedia page and display it on webView1.

The Wikipedia activity code below.

```
public class Wikipedia extends Activity {

String query;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_wikipedia);
}

public void openwikipedia (View view){
    //String query = bundle.getString(query);
    String url = "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search="+ query;
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

}

I'm having some trouble understanding how to pass the variable from one activity to the other and how to get the string from the TextView query.

I tried some solutions presented on Stack Overflow, but either wasn't able to get it working or couldn't really understand the procedure given.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly:

```
TextView term =  (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);
```

will give you a runtime error because you cannot intialize the TextView before you have set the content view of the page (the layout).

So, in `onCreate`, you have this line of code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_wikipedia);
```

So after that line of code, you can initialize the TextView `term` to be any TextView in the layout. For example:

```
TextView term; // declare here

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // but initialize here
    term = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.searchtext);

    WebView intView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    intView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

}
```

---

Secondly:

You never actually initialized `query` after declaring it: `String query;` at the top of the class.

You need to get the text that the user searched in the EditText, probably like so:

```
EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextId);
String query = et.getText().toString();
```

---

Finally:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, Wikipedia.class);
 intent.putExtra("query", query);
 startActivity(intent);
```

`intent.putExtra` is "attaching" the `query` String to the intent. Then you can receive the `query` String in the other activity (`Wikipedia`), like this:

```
String query = "";
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
    query = bundle.getString("query");
}
String url = "en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search?search="+ query;
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
startActivity(i);
```

---

Note that you need to use `bundle.getString("query")` instead of `bundle.getString(query)` because `"query"` is the reference to the String extra that you attached to the intent from your other class, from this line of code:

```
intent.putExtra("query", query);
```

Comment: Almost there. I'm not getting an error, but once I click the Wikipedia button, it opens up the Hello World which is not even in the Package Explorer.

Comment: Do you mean when the `Wikipedia` activity is opened, or when `public void openwikipedia (View view){` is ran?

Comment: Just fixed it, but in the meantime, when I press the Wikipedia button, it doesn't display anything, although it changes the name of the activity on the top of the screen. So I believe I'm not being able to call the page into my webView1, which was defined on the activity_main.xml, which is the only layout I'm using.

Comment: @HBT Hmmm... I've never used a WebView, so I'm not sure what the problem could be there. However, `startActivity` shouldn't have anything to do with the WebView, should it? I have no idea on that one.

Comment: Thank you for your help, Mike. I appreciate all the time you gave to this matter. I'll keep on researching.

Answer (score 1):

To get a String from a TextView:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
String text = tv.getText().toString();
```

But actually, you have to use an EditText to get something from the user.

The way you are passing the variable to the intent is okay. To unpack it in the other activity, you have to do this:

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra("query");
```

Comment: In your case, use query instead of text as the string.

Comment: Thank you , Fedor. Yes, I needed to change the TextView for EditText. Not fully working yet, but on track.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from your `TextView`:

```
TextView my_tv = (TextView) findViewByid(R.id.your_textview_id);
String my_tv_text = my_tv.getText().toString();
```

To pass the data to your another Activity, you chose well, use `Intent`s:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, WikiPedia.class);
intent.putExtra("my_data", my_tv_text);
startActivity(intent);
```

To receive your data within your WikiPedia activity:

```
Intent passed_intent = getIntent();
String passed_text = intent.getStringExtra("my_data");
```